# Solutions of Logistic Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oiDvNs15tkE, Sal creates the differential equation $\frac{dN}{dt}=rN(1-\frac{N}{K})$ where:

1) $N$ (the population size) is a function of time ($t$)

2) $K$ is the maximum population size due to the environment's constraints

3) $r$ is a proportionality constant between $\frac{dN}{dt}$ and $N$

He shows that one of the solutions to this equation is the equation $N(t)=0$ if the initial condition is $N(0)=0$. His explanation is that if N is $0$, then $\frac{dN}{dt}=0$. My issue is that we can only say that $\frac{dN}{dt}=0$ for $t=0$. How is Sal's generalizing of $\frac{dN}{dt}=0$ for all $t$ values justified? The same goes with the solution with the initial condition $N(0)=K$: how do we know the slope is zero for all t-values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is just saying  that if we take $N(t)=0$ for every $t$ the  the equation is satisfied (which is obvious). The assumption here is that $N(t)=0$ for every $t$, not for  a particular $t$.